# need help opening url from adapter kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i need to open an item i am pulling from database and open its url in the browser.

but its not opening but if i try a different code in the onclicklistener it runs it but when i try intent to open url its failing to do so

```
class ItemHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
{
    fun bind(n: String, p: Double, u: String, item_id: Int)
    {
        itemView.item_name.text=n
        itemView.item_price.text=p.toString()
        var web:String=""+u
        web=web.replace(" ", "%20")
        Picasso.with(itemView.context).load(web).into(itemView.item_photo)

        itemView.view_browers.setOnClickListener {
            val context: Context? = null

            val url = "http://www.example.com"
            context?.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `context` to null, so the line

```
context?.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)))
```

will do nothing.

You need to use a non-null context. Show us the code that works, and we can amend it so it does what you want.